# WebApi - Sent Guid taken as a new Guid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, guid

I have an `ApiController` class with a method accepting a complex object.

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Sample/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSampleInfo([FromBody]SampleClass sampleClassObject)
    {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

When debugging, this `Controller` class method is called, but what was passed as a `Guid` in the object, shows a new `Guid` (as `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`). I'm first checking this method with *Postman*. I tried passing the object using `x-www-form-urlencoded` and also as `application/json`.

What I'm passing in *Postman*:

```
{
   "sampleID": "A9A999AA-AA99-9AA9-A999-9999999999AA",
   "otherValue": 1
}
```

I checked other issues like mine but I have tried the solutions but still I'm getting the passed `Guid` as a new `Guid`.

P.S.
The `SampleClass` looks like as follows:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public Guid sampleID { get; set; }
    public int otherValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

I have used the following `JsonConverter`.

```
public class GuidConverterCustom : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Guid) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return Guid.Empty;
            case JsonToken.String:
                string str = reader.Value as string;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                {
                    return Guid.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Guid(str);
                }
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid token type");
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (Guid.Empty.Equals(value))
        {
            writer.WriteValue("");
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue((Guid)value);
        }
    }
}
```

And included the following in the `Global.asax.cs`:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Converters.Add(new GuidConverterCustom());
    return settings;
};
```

Comment: You need to add how `SampleClass` looks as well.

Comment: can you show the class definition

Comment: @Ogglas Thank you. I updated my question.

Comment: @narekye Thank you. I updated my question.

Comment: which javascript deserializer settings do you use in your global.asax or startup.cs?

Comment: @narekye There is nothing... What should I do? I was not aware of this :(

Comment: @narekye I updated my question with the new `JsonConverter` class. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should look like this, no need for custom JsonConverter.

```
[Route("sample")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostGuid(SampleClass id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

It then works with both `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json`. If you use json do not forget the header `Content-Type: application/json`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I tried this before using the custom converter.. But still it returned only 0s :(

Comment: @Curiousity Skip Json then and use `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Send print from Postman if this does not work. Remember to clear headers when you switch.

Comment: I cleared Json headers and used `x-www-form-urlencoded` but still no change. Could you please tell me what you mean by "Send print from Postman"?

Comment: @Curiousity Update your question with a print screen from Postman so we can have a look at the request.

Comment: Oh I forgot to change the header content type. I thought it would automatically change but it hadn't and it works now. Thank you so much You pointed me in the right direction. :) :) Many many thanks...